# Two way binding without isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have a Directive which gets an Object:

```
export class MyListDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    bindToController = true;
    controller = MyListDirectiveController;
    controllerAs = "vm";
    require = ["^parentDirective"];
    restrict = "E";
    templateUrl = '/list.tpl.html';
    scope = {
        detailedObject: "="
    };
}
```

The MyListDirectiveController:

```
export class MyListDirectiveController implements IMyListScope{
        colliRelatedDetails: ColliEventGroup[];

        static $inject = ['$scope'];

        constructor(scope:any) {

        }
    }
```

And the Template (list.tpl.html):

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="listtable"
           class="table valigntoptable  collapse-table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div class="cursor-pointer" ng-click="vm.sortEventsByNumber()">Number</div>
            </th>

            <th>
                <div class="cursor-pointer" ng-click="vm.$parent.sortEventsByValue()">Value</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody ng-repeat="Event in vm.detailedObjects">
        <tr class="top-padding">
            <td>
                {{Event.number}}
            </td>

            <td>
                {{Event.value}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

As you can see I have no sort method in `MyDirectiveController`. The methods I try to address are inside the parents controller (since I need another similar list). So I need to call the methods of the `parentDirectiveController`. But how do I access them?

I can't get rid of the isolated scope, because I need the two-way binding. Otherwise the list won't update, when the sort-functions get called.

And to add new sort-Methods inside the `MyListDirectiveController`, inject the parentscope and then call the methods. But it seems as if this wouldn't be a clean way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to accomplish this.  The first would be to explicitly pass the functions from the parent to the child as parameters.  This is much more flexible but requires the functions to be specified in the markup, which may not be desired.  IE:

```
export class MyListDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    ...
    scope = {
        detailedObject: "=",
        sortEventsByNumber: "&"
    };
}

<my-list-directive detailedObject="vm.object" sortEventsByNumber="vm.numberSorter"></my-list-directive>
```

The other option is to use `require` in your directive.  This forces parent/child relationship, meaning that this directive can't function if it is placed inside a different kind of element.

You already added this to the directive, but aren't hooked up to it.  In order to access the required parent controller, you need to access it through the link function.

```
export class MyListDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    ...
    require = "^parentDirective",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, parentInstance) {
      //the fourth argument is the controller instance you require
      vm.sortEventsByNumber = parentInstance.sortEventsByNumber;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Name: <input ng-model="firstname">
    <h1>{{firstname}}</h1>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstname = "John";
    $scope.lastname = "Doe";
});
</script>

<p>Change the name inside the input field, and the model data will change automatically, and therefore also the header will change its value.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how does this have anything to do with the question?  this appears to be a basic example of angular usage.